# Does jQuery Form Plugin have call back function beforeSend:function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wso2, jquery-forms-plugin

I need to validate my form data using jquery validator plugin and custom validation methods before send a form data.I need to clarify whether jQuery Form Plugin have beforeSend call back function and if so what are the basic requirements to use beforeSend callback function?

```html
$(function(){

 var obtainFormMeta=function(formId){
  return $(formId).data();
 };
    $('#form-asset-create').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend:function(){
            alert('before send');
            $('#form-asset-create').validate();
        },
        success:function(){
            var options=obtainFormMeta('#form-asset-create');
            //alert('Aww snap! '+JSON.stringify(options));
            alert("when success");
            window.location=options.redirectUrl;
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Unable to add the asset');
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: I think it is present as per the doc - http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

Comment: I think you should return `true` or `false` in `beforesend` to proceed or cancel the request

Comment: Even though my alert inside the beforesend is not hit ..And I have my custom validation methods to chaeck the field is valid or not

Comment: As per the document it is just preparing the form. Not submitting it - **Prepares a form to be submitted via AJAX by adding all of the necessary event listeners. It does not submit the form. Use ajaxForm in your document's ready function to prepare your form(s) for AJAX submission. ajaxForm takes zero or one argument. The single argument can be either a callback function or an Options Object.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(function(){

    var obtainFormMeta=function(formId){
        return $(formId).data();
    };
    $('#form-asset-create').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend:function(){
            alert('before send');
            $('#form-asset-create').validate();
        },
        success:function(){
            var options=obtainFormMeta('#form-asset-create');
            //alert('Aww snap! '+JSON.stringify(options));
            alert("when success");
            window.location=options.redirectUrl;
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Unable to add the asset');
        }
    });

    $('#form-asset-create').ajaxSubmit();

    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false;
});
```